# Flex 4 s:List itemRenderer labels not displayed

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

I have the following s:List

```
<s:List
    id="lstOther"
    borderVisible="false"
    width="100%" height="100%"
    dataProvider="{this.handler.itemRendererType}"
    labelFunction="labelFunction"
    itemRendererFunction="itemRendererFunction">
</s:List>
```

The functions for itemRendererFunction and labelFunction look like this:

```
private function itemRendererFunction(item:Object):IFactory {
            var clazz:Class = DefaultItemRenderer;
            switch(item.data) {
                case "Security Unit":
                    clazz = CheckBox;
                    break;
                default:
                    clazz = CheckBoxEditLabel;
            }
            return new ClassFactory(clazz);
        }

        private function labelFunction(item:Object):String {
            return "testing";
        }
```

My data provider (dataProvider="{this.handler.itemRendererType}") is composed as follows:

```
public var itemRendererType:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {name:"otherLabel1", data:"Security Unit"},
        {name:"otherLabel2", data:"Test 1"},
        {name:"otherLabel3", data:"Test 2"}
    ]);
```

I first tried setting labelField in the s:List to 'name'.  Nothing showed up in the list control.  As can be seen above, I tried using a label function and returning a hard coded value ("testing").  Still nothing shows up.

Why is the text for the labels not showing up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code to your CheckBox and CheckBoxEditLabel renderers?

Answer (score 0):

My immediate guess is that `this.handler` is null;  you should debug to see why that is (what is handler anyways?).  You were right about using labelField="name", that should work, but won't show anything if you don't have any data.  Also, I'm fairly sure your itemRendererFunction isn't going to work properly since it needs to return a component that extends s:ItemRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

**this.handler** is not null.  **handler** is the actionscript class where the itemRendererType is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The following item renderer works fine with your sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    autoDrawBackground="true">
    <s:CheckBox label="{label}" />
</s:ItemRenderer>
```